# What is the logic behind the scale command in the PS/2 mouse interface?

Tags: mouse, ps2

I was reading about PS/2 mouse interface and it says the host (computer) can send the devise (mouse) a scale by 2 command (code `0xE7`) that will cause the device to scale the movement it reports to the host. The scaling function is:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| Actual movement | Report |
+-----------------+--------+
| 0               | 0      |
| 1               | 1      |
| 2               | 1      |
| 3               | 3      |
| 4               | 6      |
| 5               | 9      |
| N>5             | 2*N    |
+-----------------+--------+
```

I was wondering where these values came from and what is their use. Why is it not a normal scale by 2 function?

Answer (score 0):

Because at low speeds scaling by two could make it impossible to do small precise movements, hence at low speeds (<5) there is gentle build up to the full "2x" scaling above a movement of 5.

If it were "2x" all the time then for even the smallest motion of the mouse it would move two pixels, making it nearly impossible to to do things like CAD drawing, where you only want to move 1 pixel, without constantly switching between profiles.

Almost all mice have this kind of scaling built in these days anyway, with mouse acceleration being a factor of how fast you physically move in order to balance fine motion with fast response when large motions are required.

Comment: It doesn't check out, as the 2 being transformed to 1. It make the mouse slower than this the normal scale.